Create Daily Folder, Move Files Into it, then Move that Folder Into Achive Folder
I'm an IT Admin, but I don't know PowerShell. I created a script by googling online and playing with it, but I need a bit more functionality.
Here's a bit of background info: Every day we scan a bunch of documents into a folder called "Scans".
Inside the "Scans" folder, there is also a folder called "Archive"
This is what I'm trying to accomplish with a script:
I would like the script to run every night. If there are any files (not folders) inside the "Scans" folder,

create a folder with current date as the folder name like this (08-30-2024)
move those files based on the created date to that folder for the current date
move that folder for the current date and the files inside it, into the "Archive" folder.

If there are no files on a particular day, then the script does nothing.
I hope this makes sense.
$datecurrent = get-date -Format MM-dd-yyyy
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Scans\$datecurrent"

$DestinationFolder = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Scans$datecurrent"
$archiveFolder = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Scans\Archive"

$EarliestModifiedTime = get-date (get-date -format d)
$Files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Scans*.*"

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    if ($File.LastWriteTime -gt $EarliestModifiedTime) {
        Move-Item $File -Destination $DestinationFolder
        Write-Host "Copying $File"
    } else { 
        Write-Host "Not copying $File"
    }
}

Move-Item $DestinationFolder -Destination $ArchiveFolder


Proper formatting has been applied to your post after the fact, but please format your posts properly yourself to begin with in the future.

To start with, reduce the steps. If there are files, create the new folder directly in archives, and move the files directly into that folder. This reduces the code by about half. Also, I've broken that single, very long, run on sentence into readable ones, and formatted the steps you want to take for readability. You may want to review what I've done so you can use the concept in future posts. Making your question easy to read and understand helps get answers more quickly. :-)

Hey Ken, thank you so much for your help!

This should be all you need:
$Root = 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Scans'
$ArchiveRoot = 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Scans\Archive'

$CurrentFileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $Root -File
if ($CurrentFileList) {
    $DestinationFolder = Join-Path -Path $ArchiveRoot -ChildPath $(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd')
    New-Item -Path $DestinationFolder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    Move-Item -Path $CurrentFileList.FullName -Destination $DestinationFolder -Force
}


Hey Olaf, thank you so much for your help, works like a charm.

You're welcome. I'm glad to hear it helped.
